# How to Get Debugging Information from a Clients Version of My Application

Tags: c#, debugging

All, I appreciate I could write a module to log the processes going on in my application, but this is not implemented and I cannot seem to find an explanation on how to do the following...

A client is running my application and it is throwing an error from some user defined dynamic SQL. This make it very hard to know what the user is doing and if it is the applications fault of the SQL being executed.

The client is being a funny about providing the SQL they are executing and I need to get to the bottom of what is going on. Is there a way to get a log of what the code is doing when it crashes?

The code is written in C# and is obfuscated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is in the SQL, many databases let you know the latest query that was run, so in theory, you could try to get that info, another way will be to provide this customer with a custom version of your application that logs every ran SQL query; also if you're being provided with stack traces, some obfuscation programs let you deobfuscate those stack traces.